# DotNetCore Visual Studio 2015 does not recognize references until restart

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

When I work with .net core projects in visual studio, I must restart visual studio in order for references to be found.

When I create a new .net core project, I see visual studio restoring packages (the notification in the solution explorer). When I check the output of the restore everything looks ok - all packages are downloaded. I can also see them on my hard drive.

```
True


IsDirty              : False
FileCount            : 1
Name                 : jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js
Collection           : System.__ComObject
Properties           : System.__ComObject
DTE                  : System.__ComObject
Kind                 : {6BB5F8EE-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}
ProjectItems         : System.__ComObject
Object               : System.__ComObject
ExtenderNames        : {}
ExtenderCATID        : {610D4615-D0D5-11D2-8599-006097C68E81}
Saved                : True
ConfigurationManager : 
FileCodeModel        : 
Document             : 
SubProject           : 
ContainingProject    : System.__ComObject



True

Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\.vs\restore.dg" -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"
log  : Restoring packages for \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'BundlerMinifier.Core' in \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools' in \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.json...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\project.lock.json
log  : \\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\WebApplication4.xproj
log  : Restore completed in 11414ms.
```

But in visual studio, all references appear with the warning sign and a message that they were not found:

[image]

The properties for each reference say: `NU1001 The dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.`

I can run the project just fine but I have lots of squigly stuff in the IDE and no auto completion since the references are not identified.

Only after I restart visual studio does the references look ok. Note that after restarting studio I don't need to restore again. It just works.

It looks like restoring works but for some reason visual studio does not get updated.

I am using resharper but I disabled it and it did not fix the problem.

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, DotNetCore 1.0.1 Preview 2 2-003131 (x64), .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2.

This does not happen with .Net Framework projects, only with .Net core.